# ActionScript 3: Error #2025

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

My code works fine. It's suppose to bring in one image when the user presses 1 and swap it out for another when he / she presses 2. But, when I presses 1 or 2 after having previously pressing either the same number I get a #2025 error. Ex: Pressing 1 then pressing 1 again.

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller.
>                         at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>                         at warren_fla::MainTimeline/reportKeyDown2()

Code

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var bdata = new image1(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var bdata2 = new image2(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var bmp = new Bitmap(bdata);
var bmp2 = new Bitmap(bdata2);

function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
if (event.keyCode == 49) {
    //trace("1 is pressed");
    bmp.x = 230;
    bmp.y = 150;
    addChild(bmp);
}
if (contains(bmp2)) {
    removeChild(bmp2);
    }
}

function reportKeyDown2(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
if (event.keyCode == 50) {
    //trace("2 is pressed");
    bmp2.x = 230;
    bmp2.y = 150;
    addChild(bmp2);
    removeChild(bmp);
}

} 

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are removing `bmp` without checking if it is already a child.

```
function reportKeyDown2(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.keyCode == 50) {
        //trace("2 is pressed");
        bmp2.x = 230;
        bmp2.y = 150;
        addChild(bmp2);
        if(contains(bmp)) 
            removeChild(bmp);
    }
}
```

Also your code can be refactored into this simpler version :

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

var bdata = new image1(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var bdata2 = new image2(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var bmp = new Bitmap(bdata);
var bmp2 = new Bitmap(bdata2);

function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1) {
        swapBitmaps(bmp, bmp2);            
    } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_2) {
        swapBitmaps(bmp2, bmp);            
    }
}

function swapBitmaps(first:Bitmap, second:Bitmap):void
{
      first.x = 230;
      first.y = 150;
      addChild(first);
      if(contains(second)) {        
           removeChild(second);
      }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);
```

Answer (score 2):

In reportKeyDown(), try moving:

```
if (contains(bmp2)) {
    removeChild(bmp2);
}
```

Inside the if statement that checks the keycode:

```
function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.keyCode == 49) {
        //trace("1 is pressed");
        bmp.x = 230;
        bmp.y = 150;
        addChild(bmp);

        if (contains(bmp2)) {
            removeChild(bmp2);
        }
    }
}
```

And in reportKeyDown2, check to make sure that bmp is a child before removing it:

```
function reportKeyDown2(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.keyCode == 50) {
        //trace("2 is pressed");
        bmp2.x = 230;
        bmp2.y = 150;
        addChild(bmp2);

        if(contains(bmp))
        {
            removeChild(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're potentially adding the bmp's multiple times.  Same with removing them, but if you try to remove a child that isn't on the display list, you'll get the error you're seeing.  Try using this code in all cases where you're adding or removing:

```
if (!contains(bmp)) { addChild(bmp); }  // or bmp2

if (contains(bmp)) { removeChild(bmp); } // or bmp2
```

----------- edit -------------

OK, while obviously you can addChild without checking (since addChild will remove the object from the display tree), it's more efficient to do the check.  In fact, it seems to be about 3x faster.  This test:

```
var clip = new MovieClip();
var i,j,tin,dur;
var tries = 100000;

for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
    trace("-------------------");

    tin = new Date().time;
    for (i=0; i<tries; i++) { if (!contains(clip)) { addChild(clip); } }
    dur = new Date().time - tin;
    trace("Check Adding: "+dur);

    removeChild(clip);

    tin = new Date().time;
    for (i=0; i<tries; i++) { addChild(clip); }
    dur = new Date().time - tin;
    trace("Just Adding: "+dur);
}
```

outputs:

```
-------------------
Check Adding: 9
Just Adding: 25
-------------------
Check Adding: 8
Just Adding: 25
-------------------
Check Adding: 9
Just Adding: 24
-------------------
Check Adding: 9
Just Adding: 24
-------------------
Check Adding: 9
Just Adding: 25
```